# Installing BxSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I am a complete beginner to website design and I am trying to create a more modern website for my company. The current one is less than glamorous (Greenlite.co.uk).

After spending a lot of time trying to make a Flash banner for the homepage it occurred to me that Flash is probably quite outdated and not view able from all platforms. This is when I came across the BxSlider, and it really looks great! If only I could get it to work on my site.

I am using CoffeeCup Visual Site Designer, I then used the 'Add HTML' tool. Into the 'Insert HTML' window I have placed as follows;

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="js/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/timeline1.jpg" title="An Energy Conservation Company"></li>
 <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" title="Designers and Manufactors of Quality Lighting Controls"></li>
<li><img src="images/back12.jpg" title="Caption to go here"></li>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
mode: fade,
captions: true,
auto: true,
autoControls: false
});
});
</script>
```

I have followed, as well as I could, the instructions shown on bxslider.com. I downloaded the package from bxslider, adding the files to coffeecup and linking the location in the script. I also added my images to CoffeeCup and wrote in their location.

When I preview my website I am rewarded with my three images all shown at once, each underneath the other, with a mouse over caption. Alongside the images are a bullet point.

What I am trying to achieve is a Bxslider with auto start, displaying stop/start controls and with captions.

I have attempted many variations, the script I have shown being my original attempt.

The closest I have got to a working Bxslider is by copying code I found from a website for the old version bxslider. This gave me an image slideshow with headers. If I tried to edit the code to my specifications then it would take me back to square one.

I am entirely aware that I am likely to be making a very obvious mistake. However, to the untrained eye it's giving me nothing but headaches. Any help would be largely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javascript you've got is invalid. Try changing the Javascript to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: true,
        auto: true,
        autoControls: false
    });
  });
</script>
```

See working jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FLuRH/

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!

The javascript you've just sent is a carbon copy of what a friend sent me last night. I have also tried this in replacement of the original with the same results.

Comment: Try replacing the script/link tags from your code with the ones on the above jsfiddle (http://pastebin.com/97FCHjaG).

Comment: The only thing that has occurred to me, seeing as you've given the same answer as my (better educated) friend is that I've somehow linked the files wrong?

Comment: Yep, I'd think so - Try using the bit of code from the jsfiddle and see if the slider works, if it does then you'll know it's the linked files.

Comment: When I open the 'Insert HTML' on CoffeeCup I am shown a window with three tabs 'Body HTML', 'Header HTML' and 'Onload events'


I have been putting everything into 'Body HTML' could there be an issue there? I've copied exactly what is on the jsfiddle with the same original result of three images, one underneath the other.

Comment: Can you paste the full HTML that's being output by the page? I'm not familiar with CoffeeCup so I can't help with respect to that I'm afraid.

Comment: I've deleted everything and copied the jsfiddle you linked and it WORKS!I've been at this for two days now I should've asked sooner. I can't thank you enough, I really don't know what I am doing when it comes to this.

Comment: The only issue I have now is the previous button is off the image, creating a seperate border around it, and the captions are cut in half at the bottom. Perhaps a problem with my image sizes?

Comment: By the sounds of it yes - I'd have a play around with the image sizes, and if you're still having problems, paste what you've got into a new question and I'm sure someone will be able to help.

Comment: I think I may have to. Thank you again, really.

Answer (score 0):

i noticed some thing that might be a problem: 
You didn't closed some code part properly 
This is yours:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'fade',
            captions: true,
            auto: true,
            autoControls: false
        });
      }); 
</script>
```

This is mine:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        captions: 'true',
        auto: 'true',
        autoControls: 'false',
    });
  });
</script>
```

Also i put this code part in the "head" section and it worked.
Give it a try.
I hope i helped somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code(just create new html file where u extract bxslider folder)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".bxslider").bxSlider();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="width:700px;height:250px;align:center;padding-left:250px;">
        <ul class="bxslider">
            <li>
                <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-4.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Desert.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-4.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Desert.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <img src="http://localhost/wordpress-4.1/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Desert.jpg" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```